# Difference between np.random.permutation and np.random.choice

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between using `np.random.permutation` on a 1D array vs using `np.random.choice` with size equal to the length of the 1D array?

They seem the same to me.

Comment: You still need to set `replace` to `False` for `np.random.choice`, then they are the same (or at least they should yield the same results; things are probably different under the hood).